# Python Module Not Found, Yet Installed and in Search Path

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, conda, importerror

So I have a virtual environment where I installed the package `utility`. I know I installed it because when I do `pip install utlity` and get this output:

> Requirement already satisfied: utility in ./anaconda3/envs/SpliceBuster/lib/python3.5/site-packages (1.0)

Here's the output of `print (sys.path)`:

> ['', '/home/joel/anaconda3/envs/SpliceBuster/lib/python35.zip', '/home/joel/anaconda3/envs/SpliceBuster/lib/python3.5', '/home/joel/anaconda3/envs/SpliceBuster/lib/python3.5/plat-linux', '/home/joel/anaconda3/envs/SpliceBuster/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/home/joel/anaconda3/envs/SpliceBuster/lib/python3.5/site-packages']

When I do `import utility` in a python shell, I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: No module named 'utility'

It's confusing to me because I can import `numpy`, and when I do `pip install numpy`, the output is:

> Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./anaconda3/envs/SpliceBuster/lib/python3.5/site-packages (1.12.1)

which means that both `utility` and `numpy` are installed in the same folder, but `numpy` is found whereas `utility` isn't.

Any thoughts on what could be going on?

---

Other info:

`which python`:

> /home/joel/anaconda3/envs/SpliceBuster/bin/python

`python -V`:

> Python 3.5.0 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.

Comment: Where do you try to import the module from? Is it a Python shell or a file?

Comment: @ noxdafox both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want to use this package? Looking at [Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/utility/) there seems to be no description and the source code of the project is nowhere to be found.

Looking at the package content, it's clear the `setup.py` is incomplete as well as the package itself.

The name to import is `utilitybelt` and not `utility`, yet you will encounter other importing issues as the package depends on other third party modules which are not listed in the `setup.py`.

Comment: thank you, turns out this was not the package I wanted, rather the `utility` that I wanted was supposed to be in the same directory as my file, but I deleted it somehow! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Try to place the module's folder into the same directory where you have the script you want to execute. This way we could discard a folders' tree issue.

Comment: You refer to external libraries or packages while OP is referring in comments to one of its own py-files that include this method. So your solution will not work. Also its a bad choice of solution if project is terminated early or finished and removed afterwards while another project relies on it (dependencies). End of Review.