# Packages not being found in anaconda although being installed - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python, anaconda, package, conda

I think I am having conflict between different python versions. This is a fresh installed Ubuntu 18.04. I did not install any python other than the one that came. I installed `anaconda`, and specified the version `3.7`.

```
(pcntorch) mk@mk-ub:~/PCN-PyTorch$ python --version
Python 3.7.13
(pcntorch) mk@mk-ub:~/PCN-PyTorch$ conda deactivate
mk@mk-ub:~/PCN-PyTorch$ python --version
Python 2.7.17
```

I already installed all the necessary requirements and libraries through conda. When running [render_depth.py](https://github.com/qinglew/PCN-PyTorch/blob/master/render/render_depth.py), I get the following error.

```
blender -b -P render/render_depth.py 'ycb_cad_models_specific' 'obj_list.txt'  'outputdir' 8


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mk/PCN-PyTorch/render/render_depth.py", line 27, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
Error: File format is not supported in file '/home/mk/PCN-PyTorch/ycb_cad_models_specific'
```

When running the following command:

```
python -mpip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/mk/anaconda3/envs/pcntorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.21.6)
```

In several [questions] [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096055/importing-numpy-results-in-error-even-though-anaconda-says-its-installed), [numpy is installed but astropy says numpy is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63420188/numpy-is-installed-but-astropy-says-numpy-is-not-installed), and [this one was more specific to my problem but didn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54845900/python-module-not-found-yet-installed-and-in-search-path) , I have seen that sometimes the solution is to uninstall anaconda and install it again. But I would prefer not do to so at the moment due to some libraries I installed in conda, imath for example, and I get the same issue:

```
(pcntorch) mk@mk-ub:~/PCN-PyTorch/render$ python3 process_exr.py obj_list.txt ../outputdir/ 8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process_exr.py", line 25, in <module>
    import Imath
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Imath'
(pcntorch) mk@mk-ub:~/PCN-PyTorch/render$ python -mpip install imath
Requirement already satisfied: imath in /home/mk/anaconda3/envs/pcntorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.0.1)
```

My guess is that somehow the paths are not matching internally, but I am quite clueless...

Running `which python` in the activated environment

```
which python
/home/mk/anaconda3/envs/pcntorch/bin/python
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/home/mk/anaconda3/envs/pcntorch/lib/python37.zip', '/home/mk/anaconda3/envs/pcntorch/lib/python3.7', '/home/mk/anaconda3/envs/pcntorch/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/mk/anaconda3/envs/pcntorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/mk/anaconda3/envs/pcntorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/chamfer_3D-0.0.0-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/home/mk/anaconda3/envs/pcntorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/emd_cuda-0.0.0-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg']
```